# restoreState keeps cutplane of previous viewer state

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I have a project with multiple viewstates (viewer.setstate())
I would like to 'navigate from one state to the other

if one restoreState has a cutplane it remains in the next restore state.
how can I "turn off" the section plane when restore a next viewer state.

Answer (score 0):

While restoring a view state, you can apply a filter to decide what to be restored and what not to be restored. For example, you restore override cut planes, you can:

```
// Prevent storing cut planes while restoring a view state
viewer.restoreState( viewState, { cutplanes: false })
```

Comment: viewstate (A) has cutplanes and I want these restored, it's when I restore another viewstate (B), the cutplanes from (A) state are kept which is not what i want (is this a bug?). To resolve this I want to deactivate the cutplanes before restoring viewstate (B). I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, not sure if they are related. When trying to restoreState from state A to B, if state B has an empty array of cutplanes it will keep the cutplanes of the previous state.

I did a super dirty fix by adding a Z-cutplane very high in the model (you can get the highest coordinate at the models bounding box) but this sounds like a very bad way of fixing it. and I’m pretty sure it will come back to haunt me in the future.

Comment: Thx for confirming this, I have also implemented likewise "fix"